# GEO location distanceTo()

Tags: android, geolocation

can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

My App returns 0.0 meters if i run this on my device or emulator. it should be 1000 meters.
Even hardcoding a location into the LocationA.set.. doesn't help me..
i think it has to do with the Double - To string part..
or am i wrong?

heres my code:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location != null)
        {
            double pLong = location.getLongitude();
            double pLat = location.getLatitude();
            txtLat = Double.toString(pLat);
            txtLong = Double.toString(pLong);
            textLat.setText(Double.toString(pLat));
            textLong.setText(Double.toString(pLong));
            double distance =0;
            Location locationA = new Location("point A");
            locationA.setLatitude(location.getLatitude() /1e6);
            locationA.setLongitude(location.getLongitude() /1e6);
            Location locationB = new Location("point B");
            locationB.setLatitude(51.914282);
            locationB.setLongitude(4.615116);

            int distance2 = (int) locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
            String str = " (" + String.valueOf(distance) + " meters)";
            dist.setText(str);
        }
    }
```

\

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are outputting `String.valueOf(distance)`. Distance was initialized to `0` and then never set again. The `distanceTo` call goes into `distance2` and not `distance`.

An another note, when you are setting the latitude and longitude of `locationA`, why are you dividing be 1e6? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Thanks... sometimes all you need is another look on things... you have been very helpful!